# Why iOS terminates background apps instead of handling lack of RAM differently?

Tags: ios

All over [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) Apple mention iOS terminates apps under certain conditions, and the most popular reason seems to be freeing up some RAM. And that causes issues for apps that do not implement state restoration - some of the content user is working on and stepped away from for a moment could be easily erased. There's even a [16 page thread on Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5380124) where users complaining about that.

- Is anyone aware why iOS actually terminates apps instead of moving memory occupied by them onto disc/swap?
- Does termination actually provide considerable performance improvement compared to other means?

Comment: Why waste disk storage for swapping app memory to disk when the developer can implement state restoration to be more efficient?

Comment: "And that causes issues for apps that do not implement state restoration" maybe that's why they introduced state restoration?

Comment: Android has the same general approach - it's not specifically an iOS "issue".

Comment: "Why waste disk storage for swapping app memory to disk when the developer can implement state restoration to be more efficient?" - probably to improve user experience? The thing is lots of apps still don't implement that and get through the review process just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for responses. I had to do some research to answer this question, though. So I was looking for more understanding that led into "app termination" decisions. I know, there are some smart people working in Apple, but for me it always help to understand the reason something is build "this way" rather then just following it.

It turned down into these 2 questions

- Why iOS terminates apps instead of freeing memory by paging out (swapping)?
- Does termination provide considerable performance win?

To understand that I dug a bit into the history of iPhone. There's a video that was accessible on iTunes, unfortunately the link does not work anymore. Anyways, the video was introducing the very first version of multitasking on iPhone 3G (or was it 3GS? Not sure which device starts to support multitasking).

Nowadays iPhone devices are quite advanced in terms of hardware. Those are actually more advanced then some desktops we had 7-10 years ago, which already have had incorporated swapping long ago. But if we look for first iPhone releases, those are not that much advanced in terms of hardware. iPhone 3G is 620 Mhz ARM and 128 RAM. iPod touch 1gen had 400mhz ARM. And multitasking was supposed to run on all the devices of that time.

If we take a look at iOS, it was always has the smoothness of animations in priority; taking look at hardware I see it would be challenging to have both snappy and responsive device along with processing swapping background applications memory, so it seems very logical and very fair to terminate apps. A year or two later Apple provided APIs to facilitate implementation state restoration.

But if we look at the current iPhones and iPads - they do have enough power in order not to terminate apps and just drop their memory on disk without any drop downs in animations and foreground app performance. Why not add that on latest devices? I assume this is common for the software industry; new features often prioritised higher then improvements on existing workflows; Apple has been releasing MobileMe, support for Retina displays, AutoLayout, iCloud - so I can understand that cool improvements of already existing features has been sacrificed.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is paging, or more accurately, page swapping. The iOS version of BSD Unix does not perform paging, for lots of reasons. Here are a few educated guesses:

It's too power-hungry for a mobile device.

Flash memory can't handle the churn involved in paging. Flash memory has a limited number of lifetime write cycles per storage location, and paging would chew through the life of the flash chip.

As the other poster pointed out, swapping to disk would use up available disk space, which is also limited. Not a problem when you have a 500 GB drive, but it is a big problem on a device with only 16 GB of HD and 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Duncan, thanks for your response! If you would make such a decision of whether or not allow paging out on iOS, or make it available via switch in settings, what decision would you make? Apple installs flash memory on MBAs, so flash chip lifetime does not sound like a case to me. Disc space hint sounds reasonable.

Comment: To be pedantic, iOS does use memory paging/virtual memory, it just does do the memory swapping to secondary slower memory. If it didn't using paging it would run into memory fragmentation issue. Logical memory address are mapped to different physical memory address but it doesn't allocate more pages than can be stored in physical memory.

Comment: @Nathan, By paging I meant page swapping, page faults, etc. I guess you're right that paging means mapping blocks of memory from virtual to physical. I'm used to using the term to refer to page swapping.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get an answer for this question here. Apple don't explain the inner workings of iOS and anything else is going to be guesswork.

Here's my guesswork:

iOS is a heavily resource constrained environment. Memory is limited but so is disk space - a 16GB iPhone has 1GB of RAM, so "swapping to disk" isn't really something that can be freely applied. When do you stop? How do you know this isn't already being done, but there is only a limited swap in place?

The primary goal of iOS has always been to prioritise responsiveness of the foreground app. Anything other than warning, then closing background apps would probably impact this too much. If there are 15 apps in the background then imagine the processor load on nicely swapping the memory out for each process?

Comment: If you would make such a decision of whether or not allow paging out on iOS, or make it available via switch in settings, what decision would you make? According on Duncan's mention I look through this Apple's manual: http://goo.gl/qURGBu and apparently iOS does not support page outs at all. Most background apps are "suspended" and don't consume CPU time. In your opinion, if a system would "page out" applications on lack of space, instead of terminating them, would that make iOS animations sluggish or considerably degrade performance? Good point that I'm likely to get only guesswork here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the RAM that was saved onto the disc would be much slower. It's better to cut the program then having it run poorly. I think that answered both questions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with apps that don't provide state restoration is easily solved by providing state restoration.

Just killing apps when the system runs out of memory is a huge performance gain. Consider that the system usually runs out of memory when you launch another app, and any action that is done instead of killing old apps would have to be done before launching the new app; that's about the most performance critical point in time.

And for at least five years you have been told that when your app goes to the background, you should store just enough state to come back to that state if your app is restarted.